# AjaxFileUpload control's Drop zone not visible on IE10

Tags: upload, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have [Ajax file upload control](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx) on an aspx page. The drag and drop zone of the control is visible on Chrome and mozilla but not on IE10. I understand that it should be visible on browsers which support HTML5 and CSS3. I believe IE10 has the support.

I went through the CSS and found this difference

```
<div class="ajax__fileupload_dropzone" id="ctl00_Mainform_AjaxFileUpload_Html5DropZone" style="width: 100%; height: 60px; visibility: visible;">Drop files here</div>  (In Chrome)
<div class="ajax__fileupload_dropzone" id="ctl00_Mainform_AjaxFileUpload_Html5DropZone" style="width: 100%; height: 60px; display: none; visibility: hidden;"/> (In IE10)
```

In case of IE10, The display is set to none and visibility to hidden.

My question specifically is
At what point is this browser specific css rendered? so that I could get to why this is happening even when there is support for HTML5 and CSS3
I believe I cannot change this property in my code as it would be overwritten again in case of IE10.

**EDIT:**
I did try to edit the css by setting display to "block" and visibility to "visible". But this creates a disproportionate view with scroll bars which is not an ideal solution in my case

Answer (score 0):

catch it with jquery.

```
// let the dropzone load first
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.ajax__fileupload_dropzone').text('Drag Drop/Click');
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        $('.ajax__fileupload_dropzone').css({'visibility': 'visible','display':''});
    }

}, 10);
```

this got it to show but it would not work right.  I updated the toolkit from 15.1.2.0 to 15.1.3.0 and this seems to fix the problem.  The odd thing is the night before I had no problems with IE.